# My api request is returning nothing, no error message either

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

when i run this file, i get nothing. If i run instead `console.log(getInfo());` at the end i just get `Promise <pending>`. Please help.

```
function getInfo(){
    var url = `https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/cheddar%20cheese?fields=item_name%2Citem_id%2Cbrand_name%2Cnf_calories%2Cnf_total_fat&appId=${apiId}&appKey=${apiKey}`;
    return(
    fetch(url)
    .then(data=>{

        return JSON.parse(data);
     })
    );
}

getInfo().then(result =>{
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: @JF How is linked Question related to current Question?

Answer (score 3):

This is not how you use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). Use `response.json()` like this (logs an error because I don't know the `apiId` and `apiKey`):

```js
function getInfo(){
  var apiId = 1;
  var apiKey = 1;
  var url = `https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/cheddar%20cheese?fields=item_name%2Citem_id%2Cbrand_name%2Cnf_calories%2Cnf_total_fat&appId=${apiId}&appKey=${apiKey}`;
  return fetch(url).then(response => response.json());
}

getInfo().then(data => console.log(data));
```